# Filename completion in vim with xterm doesn't work as expected

Tags: vim, special-characters, filenames, xterm, autocomplete

Something funny is going on with my `vim`. I'm using it through `xterm`. I want to be able to autocomplete filenames that I try to open.

For example:

```
# Cursor is | character
:o exam|
:o exam|<TAB>
:o examplefile.txt|
```

I was sure `vim` supported this, but it's not working for me. When I hit `<TAB>` an `^I` character is inserted *instead* of completing the filename:

```
:o exam|<TAB>
:o exam^I|
:o exam^I|<TAB>
:o exam^I^I|
```

However, `<TAB>` works fine in `bash` in `xterm` - it correctly completes filenames and *doesn't* expand to `^I`.

Is my terminal configured incorrectly? Do I need some `stty` voodoo? Or is it something else entirely?

**Edit**

`:e` *does* work for me - seems like only `:o` doesn't...

Comment: For completeness: make sure you do not have compatible mode set (`:h 'cp'`) - auto-completion on command line works only when `:set nocp`. Some systems I have seen were shipped with /etc/vimrc containing `set cp`, making VIM to work more like a vi.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

:o is not really supported in vim. Try typing :h :o, you'll see this:

> Vim does not support open mode, since
>   it's not really useful.  For those
>   situations where ":open" would start
>   open mode Vim will leave Ex mode,
>   which allows executing the same
>   commands, but updates the whole screen
>   instead of only one line.

I think you're confusing :o and :e (they're not the same).

Comment: It seems that :o simply doesn't tab-complete.

Comment: Not supported, see e.g. the documentation http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/vi_diff.html#:open or this thread http://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=774684

Answer (score 2):

`edit` works for me:

```
:e exam|<TAB>
```

Comment: Hrm... it works for me too! Any idea what the discrepancy with `:o` could be?

Comment: Seems that `:o` is not useful - whatever it was supposed to do, probably a legacy option, so has less functionality I guess ... I always use `:e` for `edit` files so I never noticed.